# 名乗る used as a transitive verb

Tags: translation, transitivity

What does 名乗る mean when used with the particle を, as in this sentence?

風評は目撃者を名乗る

I can only seem to find the intransitive on internet dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

名乗る can be used more often than not as a transitive / reflexive verb.

For example:

- 彼は弁護士を名乗る
  He calls himself a lawyer.
- 菅原と名乗る人
  a person called Sugahara
- 援助者と名乗る詐欺漢
  a swindle who calls himself an aid

However, 風評は目撃者を名乗る doesn't make sense unless it is followed by words or a phrase that complement the sentence.